# Which is the first integer that an IEEE 754 float is incapable of representing exactly?

Tags: types, floating-point, ieee-754

For clarity, if I'm using a language that implements IEE 754 floats and I declare:

```
float f0 = 0.f;
float f1 = 1.f;
```

...and then print them back out, I'll get 0.0000 and 1.0000 - exactly.

But IEEE 754 isn't capable of representing all the numbers along the real line. Close to zero, the 'gaps' are small; as you get further away, the gaps get larger.

So, my question is: **for an IEEE 754 float, which is the first (closest to zero) integer which cannot be exactly represented?** I'm only really concerned with 32-bit floats for now, although I'll be interested to hear the answer for 64-bit if someone gives it!

I thought this would be as simple as calculating 2<sup>bits_of_mantissa</sup> and adding 1, where *bits_of_mantissa* is how many bits the standard exposes. I did this for 32-bit floats on my machine (MSVC++, Win64), and it seemed fine, though.

Comment: Why did you add one if you wanted an irrepresentable number? And what number did you use or get? And is this homework? And your question title says "integer" but your question says "float".

Comment: Because I figured that maxing the mantissa would give me the highest representable number.
2^22.
No, it's a curiosity question. I've always felt guilty putting ints in floats, even when I know that the int in question is always going to be very small. I want to know what the upper limit is.
As far as I can tell, the title and question are the same, just phrased differently.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the first double that deviates from its corresponding long by delta?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732612/whats-the-first-double-that-deviates-from-its-corresponding-long-by-delta)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848700/biggest-integer-that-can-be-stored-in-a-double ?

Comment: @ks1322 Your edit makes the sentence ungrammatical. “however many” is not equivalent to “how many” and is used correctly in the original sentence (whereas “how many” does not fit). See http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic9565.html or many other Google results if you want to see more examples of that sort of phrase.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Completely disagree, even after reading your link (which doesn't seem to say anything about contexts in which "however" fits but "how" doesn't).

Comment: @KyleStrand reverted^2. I don't know why one seemed more correct to me than the other at the time. Now they both seem awkward compared to “… is the number of bits…”

Comment: @PascalCuoq Thanks for giving the matter further consideration and making the change! I agree, "the number" would be a superior phrasing.

Answer (score 298, accepted):

2<sup>mantissa bits + 1</sup> + 1

The +1 in the exponent (mantissa bits + 1) is because, if the mantissa contains `abcdef...` the number it represents is actually `1.abcdef... × 2^e`, providing an extra implicit bit of precision.

Therefore, the first integer that **cannot** be accurately represented and will be rounded  is:

- For 32-bit floats, 16,777,217 (2<sup>24</sup> + 1).
- For 64-bit floats, 9,007,199,254,740,993 (2<sup>53</sup> + 1).

Here's an example in CPython 3.10, which uses 64-bit floats:

```
>>> 9007199254740993.0
9007199254740992.0
```

Comment: I declared a `float` and set it equal to 16,777,217. But when I printed it using `cout` it resulted in 16,777,216. I'm using `C++`. Why can't I get 16,777,217?

Comment: @sodiumnitrate Check the question title. 16777217 is the first integer **incapable** of being represented exactly.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I got confused, sorry about that. I have another question though: after 16777216, shouldn't the next integer that is representable be 2*16777216? When I run a similar program, I get 16777218 by adding 2 to 16777126.

Comment: The next integer is indeed 16777218, because 2 now becomes the last significant binary digit.

Comment: How would you go about this if the number were to be even?

Comment: Sorry, and also, how would we find, say , the second smallest integer?

Comment: In C++, that's `(1 << std::numeric_limits<float>::digits) + 1`, and in C,  `(1 << FLT_MANT_DIG) + 1`. The former is nice because it can be part of a template. Don't add the +1 if you just want the largest representable integer.

Comment: @HenrySchreiner you should submit that as an answer, it is a good and concise answer for C++ and C.

Comment: Related: [`digits10`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10)

Comment: What about largest negative numbers for `float` and `double`?

Comment: @AlanSTACK The negative number with largest magnitude is just the negation of the position one.

Comment: So `-16,777,217` and `-9,007,199,254,740,993`? Or are they 1 off or something.

Comment: You can use this to examine floating point bit representations and find the min/max integer values: https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html here is another one for 16, 32, 64 and 128 bit floating point: http://weitz.de/ieee/

Answer (score 53):

The largest value representable by an *n* bit integer is 2<sup>*n*</sup>-1. As noted above, a `float` has 24 bits of precision in the significand which would seem to imply that 2<sup>24</sup> wouldn't fit.

*However*.

Powers of 2 within the range of the exponent are exactly representable as 1.0×2<sup>*n*</sup>, so 2<sup>24</sup> *can* fit and consequently the first unrepresentable integer for `float` is 2<sup>24</sup>+1. As noted above. Again.

Comment: This clearly explained the "extra implicit bit of precision" part of the other.  Thanks.