# What are the limit values of int32 till which int32 to float conversion can work without rounding to nearest value?

Tags: c, types, integer

I am trying to convert int32 values to float and when i try to convert values above 0x0FFFFF the last decimal pointed is always rounded to nearest value. I know that when a value is not fitting to the destination float member it will be rounded but i need to know which is the limit value for this.
e.g. 11111111 (0x69F6BC7) is printed as 111111112.0 .

Comment: Can you please update the question with the code snippet you tried?

Comment: @BharatS: This is not a debugging question and does not require showing code. The question is clear.

Comment: You do know that the `float` type can (mostly) only store about 7 decimal figures accurately?

Comment: The problem is i am using a tool  called Embedded Wizard it has its own language based on c/cpp but it just support float and not double. I have developed a numeric keypad and when user presses 1111111.11 I am storing it as 111111111 and divide by unit of digit precision(in this case it is 100). While doing that I need to convert  111111111 to  float and then divide by 100.0 to store this value for user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Largest odd integer that can be represented as a float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52267201/largest-odd-integer-that-can-be-represented-as-a-float)

Comment: duplicates: [Which is the first integer that an IEEE 754 float is incapable of representing exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3793838/995714), [Finding the smallest integer that can not be represented as an IEEE-754 32 bit float](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3890123/995714), [Range of integers that can be expressed precisely as floats / doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15643067/995714), [Smallest integer not representable in single precision floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27207149/995714)

Comment: @phuclv: None of those four are for C except the second, and that one has no answer that would be a good solution here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum integer value of a `float` significand is `FLT_RADIX/FLT_EPSILON - 1`. By “integer value” of a significand, I mean the value when it is scaled so that its lowest bit represents a value of 1.

The value `FLT_RADIX/FLT_EPSILON` is also representable in `float`, since it is a power of the radix. `FLT_RADIX/FLT_EPSILON + 1` is not representable in `float`, so converting an integer to `float` might result in rounding if the integer exceeds `FLT_RADIX/FLT_EPSILON` in magnitude.

If it is known that `INT_MAX` exceeds `FLT_RADIX/FLT_EPSILON`, you can test this for a non-negative `int x` with `(int) (FLT_RADIX/FLT_EPSILON) < x`. If it is not known that `FLT_RADIX/FLT_EPSILON` can be converted to `int` successfully, more complicated tests may be needed.

Very commonly, C implementations use the IEEE-754 binary32 format, also known as “single precision,” for `float`. In this format, `FLT_RADIX/FLT_EPSILON` is 2<sup>24</sup> = 16,777,216.

These symbols are defined in `<float.h>`. For `double` or `long double`, replace `FLT_EPSILON` with `DBL_EPSILON` or `LDBL_EPSILON`. `FLT_RADIX` remains unchanged since it is the same for all formats.

Theoretically, a perverse floating-point format might have an abnormally small exponent range that makes `FLT_RADIX/FLT_EPSILON - 1` not representable because the significand cannot be scaled high enough. This can be disregarded in practice.