# Can all 32 bit ints be exactly represented as a double?

Tags: double, ieee-754

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is the first integer that an IEEE 754 float is incapable of representing exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793838/which-is-the-first-integer-that-an-ieee-754-float-is-incapable-of-representing-e)

This is basic question, my feeling is that the answer is yes(int = 32 bits, double = 53 bit mantisa + sign bit).

Basically can asserts fire?

```
int x = get_random_int();
double dx = x;
int x1 = (int) dx;
assert(x1 ==x);
if  (INT_MAX-10>x)
 {
       dx+=10;
       int x2=(int) dx;
       assert(x+10 == x2);
 }
```

Obviously stuff involving complicated expressions with divisions and similar stuff (    (int)(5.0/3*3) is not the same as 5/3*3)wont work, but I wonder do conversions and adition/substraction(if no overflow occurs) preserve equivalence.

Comment: I wouldnt say duplicate, though idk what duplicate means... I mean I could get my A from some of A there but Q is not the same. :)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: it's essentially asking the same question. Any (good) answer to the other one would be a good answer to this one as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*If* the number of bits in the mantissa is >= the number of bits in the integer, then the answer is yes.  In your question you give specific, known sizes for `int` and the mantissa of `double`, but it's useful to know that this is **not** guaranteed by the 2003 C++ standard, which says nothing about the relative sizes of `int` and `double`'s mantissa.

Note that C and C++ are not required to use IEEE 754 floating-point arithmetic.  According to 3.8.1/8 of the 2003 C++ standard,

> The value representation of floating-point types is implementation-defined.

In fact C++ allows floating point representations that don't even use binary mantissas.  For C, #including <limits.h> can be used to infer information about fundamental types.  In particular, if `FLT_RADIX` raised to the power `DBL_MANT_DIG` is greater than or equal to `INT_MAX`, then all `int` values can be represented exactly.  In C++, the relevant quantities are named `numeric_limits<double>::radix`, `numeric_limits<double>::digits` and `numeric_limits<int>::max()`.

Given two integer operands and an operation that always produces an integer from integer operands (such as `+` or `*`, but not `/`), all IEEE 754 rounding modes will produce an integer exactly.  If this integer is representable in an `int` (and therefore exactly representable in a `double`, given our assumption that its mantissa is at least as wide as an `int`), then it will be the same integer you would get by using the corresponding integer operation.  Any sensible FP implementation will preserve the above guarantees, even if it is not IEEE 754 compliant.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. All *N* bit ints can be represented in a floating point representation that has at least *N-1* mantissa bits (because of the implicit leading 1 bit that doesn't need to be stored) and an exponent that can store at least *N*, i.e. has *log(N)+1* bits.

So you can store an `int32_t` in a floating point value with 31 bits of mantissa, five bits of exponent, and one sign bit, which fits in a typical `double` but not a `float`. Conversely, a `float` with only 24 bits of mantissa can only accurately store `int`s with up to 25 bits, i.e. +/-33,554,431.

Comment: Single precision has 23 explicit bits (so can represent all integers with up to 24 bits, not 25).

Comment: Good point about the leading 1-bit and the need for a sufficiently large exponent. While it's hard to imagine an FP implementation with bits(exponent) < log(bits(mantissa)), it pays to be specific about these things!

Comment: Stephen is right about my off-by-one error on the range of a float. So the effective range is +/-16,777,215.