# assumption on floating point conversion: (int)(float)n == n

Tags: c, ieee-754, floating-point-conversion

May I assume that `(int)(float)n == n` for any `int n`? At least I need this for non-negative, 31 bits values.

**addendum.** What about `(int)(double)n ==n`?

Comment: if n is already int, why cast?

Comment: My ints go into an array of floats for some computation.

Comment: I'd suggest you try this program: http://ideone.com/iADlOt

Comment: @haccks Why wouldn't this compile?

Comment: Very closely related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793838/which-is-the-first-integer-that-an-ieee-754-float-is-incapable-of-representing-e and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269523/can-all-32-bit-ints-be-exactly-represented-as-a-double

Comment: @haccks If you read the program, you would realize that it outputs all floats for which a conversion from int to float and back again does not preserve the value. i.e. it prints all n for which (int)(float)n != n , demonstrating the that the assumption of the OP is false.

Comment: @H2CO3; Sorry for the comment. I misread `==` as `=`.

Comment: @nos; In fact I was curious about the variable initialization. (which are already initialized in that program, did't noticed that).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you can't. For `int`s that can't be represented exactly by a `float`, this will fail.

(The reason: `float` is generally a 32-bit IEEE-754 floating-point value. It only has 24 bits of precision, the rest is reserved for the exponent and the sign. So if your integer has more significant binary digits than 23, and it doesn't happen to be a multiple of an appropriate power of two, then it can't be represented precisely as a `float`.)

> addendum. What about (int)(double)n ==n?

It's the same. For `int`s that can't be represented as a `double`, the comparison won't always yield true. However, generally, `int` is not long enough to accomplish this -- the widely-accepted implementation of `double` is a 64-bit IEEE-754 floating-point number which has 53 bits of precision, whereas `int`s tend to be at most 32 bits long. But you can always try to repeat the experiment with a `long` or a `long long` and a `double` instead.

Here's a demo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n = (1 << 24) + 1;

    printf("n == n: %d\n" , n == n);
    printf("n == (int)(float)n: %d\n", n == (int)(float)n);

    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
n == n: 1
n == (int)(float)n: 0
```

Comment: I'm curious; which ints can't be represented as a float? those out of bounds?

Comment: @MitchWheat: e.g. 2^24 + 1.

Comment: ah, yes. those out of bounds of IEEE float.

Comment: @MitchWheat I'm sure you know it. And I'm sure you know that I was already editing my answer.

Comment: Considering the presented cast, this assumption would be true, because the compiler wouldn't really do a conversion anyway. For a real world usage of casting back and forth, the assumption would be wrong as already pointed out by the answer. from H2CO3.

Comment: @Devolus How do you do it won't do the conversion? This is not an invariant conversion that can be optimized away. The compiler **has to** do it.

Comment: @Devolus That would be a buggy compiler.

Comment: Is the assumption valid if n < 2^23 ?

Comment: @WiSaGaN: For floating-point operations, the compiler is free to use types with precision wider than that required (C99, 5.2.4.2.2).  So it would be free to optimize `(int)(float)x` to `x` (for `int` x, at least).

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini: Bear in mind that IEEE-754 floats have an implicit leading binary 1.  So it's everything below 2^24 + 1.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth It is not a type but two cast operations, isn't it? And the observable behavior are different.

Comment: @WiSaGaN: But it's free to "use" a wider intermediate type.  I believe I've seen Visual C++ do this sort of optimization (although I'm on a Mac now, so can't verify it ;) ).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth That'll be too complicated. First RVO, then this. I think I'll switch to golang. :D

Comment: Is there any guarantee (in IEEE-754) about the validity of the assumption for small integers?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: The C standard requires that casts and assignments convert the value to the nominal type; excess precision must be eliminated.

Comment: Suggest "So if your integer has more significant binary digits than 24"  (not 23).