# Casting from uint64_t to double results in incorrect values

Tags: c, casting, type-conversion, double, uint64

When casting from a large *uint64_t* value to a *double*. The results are not as expected. Why is this, and is there a way to solve it. I'm using gcc 8.3.0

```
int main
{
   uint64_t var64 = 844421103279395000;

   printf("var64     = %llu\n", var64 );

   double varDouble = (double)var64;

   printf("varDouble = %lf\n", varDouble );

   return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows :

```
var64     = 844421103279395000
varDouble = 844421103279394940.000000
```

Comment: I'd suggest looking into how floating-point numbers are stored. You can always expect to lose precision when the number of bits of a number you want to store is greater than the number of bits in the mantissa of a floating-point number. According to Wikipedia, you can store 15.95 decimal digits in a 64-bit IEEE 754 floating-point number.

Comment: `double` has typically up to 53 bits precision, compared to 64.

Comment: there are so many duplicates: [Are all integer values perfectly represented as doubles?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43655668/995714), [biggest integer that can be stored in a double](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1848700/995714), [Can all 32 bit ints be exactly represented as a double?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13269523/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which is the first integer that an IEEE 754 float is incapable of representing exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793838/which-is-the-first-integer-that-an-ieee-754-float-is-incapable-of-representing-e)

Comment: Engineer999, "The results are not as expected." --> Exactly what did you expect?

Comment: All, note the `double` output is not the expected `844421103279394944.000000` either.  We have more going on that usual `double` to `uint64_t` issue.  Code, for some reasons ,is not printing the `double` as well as code could.  Perhaps just a weak library.

Answer (score 5):

A `double`, assuming it uses IEE754 double-precision representation, can only hold 53 bits of precision.  A `uint64_t` uses all 64 bits as value bits, meaning that there are some values that can be stored exactly in a `uint64_t` that cannot be stored exactly in a `double`.

In your example, 844421103279395000 has a hex representation of `0‭BB7 FC84 FDCF D0B8‬`.  The closest value with 53 bits of precision is `0‭BB7 FC84 FDCF D080` which is ‭844421103279394944‬ in decimal.  This value is close to what is being displayed, with the difference probably due to how `printf` handles writing significant digits.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks for catching that.  Fixed.