# Are there any whole numbers which the double cannot represent within the MIN/MAX range of a double?

Tags: floating-point, precision, ieee-754

I realize that whenever one is dealing with IEEE 754 doubles and floats, some numbers can't be represented especially when one tries to represent numbers with lots of digits after the decimal point.  This is well understood but I was curious if there were any whole numbers within the MIN/MAX range of a double (or float) that couldn't be represented and thus needed to be rounded to the nearest representable IEEE 754 representation?

For instance very large numbers are sometimes represented in doubles or floats even if they are whole numbers.  Clearly using a straight up int64 or some such large integer datatype would be better but people still use doubles for large numbers every so often.

Are there any numbers that can be called out as non-representable or can you give me a mathematical reason why it wouldn't be a problem?

Comment: JavaScript is just one place where the practice occurs; see related older thread [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Sure, there are whole numbers that are not representable as double-precision floating points.

All whole numbers not exceeding `Pow(2, 53)` or `9007199254740992`, *are* representable. From `Pow(2, 53)` to `Pow(2, 54)` (that's `18014398509481984`), only even numbers are representable. The odd numbers will be rounded.

Of course it continues like that. From `Pow(2, 54)` to `Pow(2, 55)` only the multiples of 4 (those whole numbers which 4 divides) are representable, from `Pow(2, 55)` to `Pow(2, 56)` only multiples of 8, and so on.

This is because the [double-precision floating-point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) has 53 bits (binary digits) for the mantissa (significand).

It is easy to verify my claims. For example, take the number `10000000000000001` as an `integer64`. Convert it to `double` and then back to `integer64`. You will see the precision loss.

When you take very large double-precision numbers, certainly a very little percentage of the whole numbers is representable. For example near `1E+300` (which is between `Pow(2, 996)` and `Pow(2, 997)`) we are talking multiples of `Pow(2, 944)` (`1.4870169084777831E+284`). This is consistent with the fact that a `double` is precise up to approximately 16 decimal figures. So a whole number with 300 figures will be "remembered" only by its first approx. 16 figures (actually 53 binary digits).

---

Addition: The first power of ten that is not exactly representable is `1E+23` (or 100 sextillions, short scale naming style). Near that number, only integral multiples of `16777216` (that is `Pow(2, 24)`) are representable, but ten to the 23rd power is clearly not a multiple of two to the 24th power. The prime factorization is `10**23 == 2**23 * 5**23`, so we can divide evenly by two only 23 times, not 24 times as required.

Comment: Some related threads (each one has many other related threads): [Which is the first integer that an IEEE 754 float is incapable of representing exactly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793838/) and [biggest integer that can be stored in a double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848700/)

Comment: "All whole numbers not exceeding `Pow(2, 53)`". What about negative whole numbers? I guess it is simply symmetrical (unlike two's compliment) because there is an explicit sign bit, plus 52 mantissa bits (and an implicit leading '1').

Comment: @Harry Yes, you are right, positive and negative are entirely symmetrical for an IEEE `double`. It is so symmetrical that we have a positive zero and a negative zero. They seem equivalent, but you can see their difference if you divide positive one by each of them (the result becomes positive infinity respectively negative infinity, and these are often presented differently to the user).