# Is it possible for "floor" to return an inaccurate result due to floating point rounding error?

Tags: c++, floating-point

I understand that floating point numbers can often include rounding errors.

When you take the floor or ceiling of a float (or double) in order to convert it to an integer, will the resultant value be exact or can the "floored" value still be an approximation?

Basically, is it possible for something like floor(3.14159265) to return a value which is essentially 2.999999, which would convert to 2 when you try to cast that to an int?

Comment: The answer depends on the precision. For a small number (say 3) there will be no loss. For huge numbers, there will be loss as they can't be represented by a floating point value. You may find interesting and accurate information here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @johand: True, but that loss was already there before you called `floor`. `floor` should not introduce additional imprecision.

Comment: @johand. The answer does not depend upon precision. The `floor()` function is exact. Precision is only relevant to the input to the function. The function itself is exact.

Comment: @Thilo: Your right, floor doesn't introduce additional imprecision, it's behavior is well explained by David Heffernan below. I was mistaken and thought about the java Math.floor() which returns a double (And then I was wrong again since the double can accurately represent 32bits integers. Not longs though... )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is it possible for something like floor(3.14159265) to return a value which is essentially 2.999999?

The `floor()` function returns an floating point value that is an exact integer. So the premise of your question is wrong to begin with.

Now, `floor(x)` returns the nearest integral value that is not greater than `x`. It is always true that

```
floor(x) <= x
```

and that there exists no integer `i`, greater than `floor(x)`, such that `i <= x`.

Looking at `floor(3.14159265)`, this returns `3.0`. There's no debate about that. Nothing more to say.

Where it gets interesting is if you write `floor(x)` where `x` is the result of an arithmetic expression. Floating point precision and rounding can mean that `x` falls on the wrong side of an integer. In other words, the true value of the expression that yields `x` is greater than some integer, `i`, but that `x` when evaluated using floating point arithmetic is less than `i`.

Comment: floor does not return an integer.  It returns a double, according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/floor/.  Where does it say floor returns an integer?

Comment: The sentence “The floor() function returns an integer and not a floating point value” may appear to say that the *type* of the result is an integer type, which is not the case. `floor()` returns a value of a floating-point type that, by definition, always represents an integer.

Comment: @PascalCuoq You are right. I've tried to edit to correct the details.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that it is possible to guarantee that a floating point value is an exact integer.

Answer (score 5):

Small integers are representable exactly as floats, but big integers are not.

But, as others pointed out, big integers not representable by float will never be representable by a non-integer, so `floor()` will never return a non-integer value. Thus, the cast to `(int)`, as long as it does not overflow, will be correct.

But how small is *small*? Copying shamelessly from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793838/which-is-the-first-integer-that-an-ieee-754-float-is-incapable-of-representing-e):

> For `float`, it is 16,777,217 (2<sup>24</sup> + 1).
>   For `double`, it is 9,007,199,254,740,993 (2<sup>53</sup> + 1).

Note that the usual range of `int` (32-bits) is 2<sup>31</sup>, so `float` is unable to represent all of them exactly. Use `double` if you need that.

Comment: Your shameless copy does not include the context that says that 2^24+1 and 2^53+1 are the smallest positive integers not representable in the respective types. Also, when applying `floor()` to a large integer whose neighbors are not representable, `floor()` works fine. Earlier computations may have made the result wrong by several units, but that's not `floor()`'s fault.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Hmmm, I think you are right. I've corrected my answer a bit.

Answer (score 5):

Interestingly, `float`s can store a certain range of integers exactly, for example:

- 1 is stored as mantissa 1 (binary 1) * exponent 2^0
- 2 is stored as mantissa 1 (binary 1) * exponent 2^1
- 3 is stored as mantissa 1.5 (binary 1.1) * exponent 2^1
- 4 is stored as mantissa 1 * exponent 2^2
- 5 is stored as mantissa 1.25 (binary 1.01) * exponent 2^2
- 6 is stored as mantissa 1.5 (binary 1.1) * exponent 2^2
- 7 is stored as mantissa 1.75 (binary 1.11) * exponent 2^2
- 8 is stored as mantissa 1 (binary 1) * exponent 2^3
- 9 is stored as mantissa 1.125 (binary 1.001) * exponent 2^3
- 10 is stored as mantissa 1.25 (binary 1.01) * exponent 2^3
  ...

As you can see, the way exponents increase works in with the perfectly-stored fractional values the mantissa can represent.

You can get a good sense for this by putting number into [this great online conversion site](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html).

Once you cross a certain threshold, there's not enough digits in the mantissa to divide the span of the increased exponents without skipping first every odd integer value, then three out of every four, then 7 out of 8 etc..  For numbers over this threshold, the issue is not that they might be different from integer values by some tiny fractional amount, its that all the representable values are integers and not only can no fractional part be represented any more, but as above some of the integers can't be either.

You can observe this in the calculator by considering:

```
Binary                             Decimal
+-Exponent Mantissa
0 10010110 11111111111111111111111 16777215
0 10010111 00000000000000000000000 16777216
0 10010111 00000000000000000000001 16777218
```

See how at this stage, the smallest possible increment of the mantissa is actually "worth 2" in terms of the decimal value represented?

> When you take the floor or ceiling of a float (or double) in order to convert it to an integer, will the resultant value be exact or can the "floored" value still be an approximation?

It's always exact.  What floor is doing is effectively wiping out any '1's in the mantissa whose significance (their contribution to value) is fractional anyway.

> Basically, is it possible for something like floor(3.14159265) to return a value which is essentially 2.999999, which would convert to 2 when you try to cast that to an int?

No.