# scipy csr_matrix from several vectors represented as list of sets

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have several sparse vectors represented as lists of tuples eg.

```
[[(22357, 0.6265631775164965),
  (31265, 0.3900572375543419),
  (44744, 0.4075397480094991),
  (47751, 0.5377595092643747)],
 [(22354, 0.6265631775164965),
  (31261, 0.3900572375543419),
  (42344, 0.4075397480094991),
  (47751, 0.5377595092643747)],
...
]
```

And my goal is to compose `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` from several millions of vectors like this.

I would like to ask if there exists some simple elegant solution for this kind of conversion without trying to stuck everything to memory.

**EDIT:**
Just a clarification: My goal is to build the 2d matrix, where each of my sparse vectors represent one row in matrix.

Comment: So is the goal to create one long vector or a 2d matrix? Are the vectors all of the same length coincidentally?

Comment: The goal is to create 2d matrix, where each of my sparse vectors will represent one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collecting `indices,data` into a structured array avoids the integer-double conversion issue.  It is also a bit faster than the `vstack` approach (in limited testing)  (With list data like this `np.array` is faster than `np.vstack`.)

```
indptr = np.cumsum([0]+[len(i) for i in vectors])
aa = np.array(vectors,dtype='i,f').flatten()
A = sparse.csr_matrix((aa['f1'], aa['f0'], indptr))
```

I substituted the list comprehension for `map` since I'm using Python3.

Indicies in the `coo` format `(data, (i,j))` might be more intuitive

```
ii = [[i]*len(v) for i,v in enumerate(vectors)])
ii = np.array(ii).flatten()
aa = np.array(vectors,dtype='i,f').flatten()
A2 = sparse.coo_matrix((aa['f1'],(np.array(ii), aa['f0'])))
# A2.tocsr()
```

Here, `ii` from the 1st step is the row numbers for each sublist.

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [3, 3, 3, 3],
 ...]]
```

This construction method is slower than the `csr` direct `indptr`.

---

For a case where there are differing numbers of entries per row, this approach works  (using `intertools.chain` to flatten lists):

A sample list (no empty rows for now):

```
In [779]: vectors=[[(1, .12),(3, .234),(6,1.23)],
                   [(2,.222)],
                   [(2,.23),(1,.34)]]
```

row indexes:

```
In [780]: ii=[[i]*len(v) for i,v in enumerate(vectors)]
In [781]: ii=list(chain(*ii))
```

column and data values pulled from tuples and flattened

```
In [782]: jj=[j for j,_ in chain(*vectors)]    
In [783]: data=[d for _,d in chain(*vectors)]

In [784]: ii
Out[784]: [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2]

In [785]: jj
Out[785]: [1, 3, 6, 2, 2, 1]

In [786]: data
Out[786]: [0.12, 0.234, 1.23, 0.222, 0.23, 0.34]

In [787]: A=sparse.csr_matrix((data,(ii,jj)))  # coo style input

In [788]: A.A
Out[788]: 
array([[ 0.   ,  0.12 ,  0.   ,  0.234,  0.   ,  0.   ,  1.23 ],
       [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  0.222,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ],
       [ 0.   ,  0.34 ,  0.23 ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ]])
```

Comment: Actually these two approaches fail when the vectors are not equal length. In that case there is always some sort of Python loop necessary and all bets are off as to what is the most efficient approach (I hide this fact in my answer by using `map`).

Comment: In that case, `itertools.chain` is a useful tool for flattening the list of lists.

Comment: Second solution with chain is exactly what I wanted. I have just fixed (replaced typo with `*ll` to `*vectors`) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

vectors = [[(22357, 0.6265631775164965),
            (31265, 0.3900572375543419),
            (44744, 0.4075397480094991),
            (47751, 0.5377595092643747)],
           [(22354, 0.6265631775164965),
            (31261, 0.3900572375543419),
            (42344, 0.4075397480094991),
            (47751, 0.5377595092643747)]]

indptr = np.cumsum([0] + map(len, vectors))
indices, data = np.vstack(vectors).T
A = csr_matrix((data, indices.astype(int), indptr))
```

Unfortunately, this way the column indices are converted from integers to doubles and back. [This works correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793838/) for up to very large matrices, but is not ideal.

Comment: Would a `coo` style input be more intuitive?

Comment: @hpaulj, normally I would say yes, but in this case the input is almost in csr format already and this was the requested format.