# Scikit learn Naive Bayes ValueError: dimension mismatch

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I am working on Naive Bayes classifier in Scikit-learn.

both during the training and predict phase I use following code to get csr_matrix from list of tuples:

```
def convert_to_csr_matrix(vectors):
    """
    convert list of tuples representation to scipy csr_matrix that is needed
    for scikit learner
    """
    logger.info("building the csr_sparse matrix representing tf-idf")
    row = [[i] * len(v) for i, v in enumerate(vectors)]
    row = list(chain(*row))
    column = [j for j, _ in chain(*vectors)]
    data = [d for _, d in chain(*vectors)]
    return csr_matrix((data, (row, column)))
```

Which I have implemented mostly based on [scipy csr_matrix from several vectors represented as list of sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31791033/scipy-csr-matrix-from-several-vectors-represented-as-list-of-sets/31795137#31795137)

Unfortunately now during the predict phase I am getting the following error:

```
File "/Users/zikes/project/taxonomy_data_preprocessing/single_classification.py", line 93, in predict
top_predictions = self.top.predict(item)
File "/Users/zikes/project/taxonomy_data_preprocessing/single_classification.py", line 124, in predict
category, res = model.predict(item)
File "/Users/zikes/project/taxonomy_data_preprocessing/single_classification.py", line 176, in predict
prediction = self.clf.predict(item)
File "/Users/zikes/.virtualenvs/taxonomy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 64, in predict
jll = self._joint_log_likelihood(X)
File "/Users/zikes/.virtualenvs/taxonomy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 615, in _joint_log_likelihood
return (safe_sparse_dot(X, self.feature_log_prob_.T)
File "/Users/zikes/.virtualenvs/taxonomy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/extmath.py", line 178, in safe_sparse_dot
ret = a * b
File "/Users/zikes/.virtualenvs/taxonomy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 354, in __mul__
raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
ValueError: dimension mismatch
```

Does anyone has idea what can be wrong? I guess that somehow sparse vectors have wrong dimensions. But I don't see why?

During the debugging I have printed out in the log mentioned `feature_log_prob_` from Naive Bayes model and it looks as:

```
[[-11.82052115 -12.51735721 -12.51735721 ..., -12.51735721 -11.60489688
-12.2132116 ]
[-12.21403023 -12.51130295 -12.51130295 ..., -11.84156341 -12.51130295
-12.51130295]]
```

And `shape`: `(2, 53961)`

My to predict `csr_matrix = (0, 7637)   0.770238101052 
(0, 21849)  0.637756432886`

And represented as list of tuples it looks as: `[(7637, 0.7702381010520318), (21849, 0.6377564328862234)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a bit of investigation of the problem I have realised that possible fix might be in method:

```
def convert_to_csr_matrix(vectors):
   """
   convert list of tuples representation to scipy csr_matrix that is needed
   for scikit learner
   """
   logger.info("building the csr_sparse matrix representing tf-idf")
   row = [[i] * len(v) for i, v in enumerate(vectors)]
   row = list(chain(*row))
   column = [j for j, _ in chain(*vectors)]
   data = [d for _, d in chain(*vectors)]
   return csr_matrix((data, (row, column)))
```

Line `return csr_matrix((data, (row, column)))` should be replaced by `return csr_matrix((data, (row, column)), shape=(len(vectors), dimension))`