# Weird C program behaviour

Tags: c, math, gcc, mingw, assertion

I have the following C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    const int opt_count = 2;

    int oc = 30;

    int c = 900;

    printf("%d %f\n", c, pow(oc, opt_count));
    assert(c == (int)(pow(oc, opt_count)));
}
```

I'm running MinGW on Windows 8.1. Gcc version 4.9.3. I compile my program with:

```
gcc program.c -o program.exe
```

When I run it I get this output:

```
$ program
900 900.000000
Assertion failed: c == (int)(pow(oc, opt_count)), file program.c, line 16

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

What is going on? I expect the assertion to pass because 900 == 30^2.

Thanks!

**Edit**

I'm not using any fractions or decimals. I'm only using integers.

Comment: What happens if you replace `%f` with `%.20f`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: What every programmer... etc etc.

Comment: @Olaf I'm aware that computers can't represent 0.1 in binary floating point. But they certainly can represent 3, 30, 900, etc all exactly.

Comment: @herugar5 And what about the intermediate calculations? Also *how* do you know `900` can be represented exactly?

Comment: @herugar5: But `log(30)` is neither integer nor exactly representable, thus `pow(30,2)=899.9999999...` and truncating to integer results in  `899`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. `Also how do you know 900 can be represented exactly?` Assuming IEEE 754: [Which is the first integer that an IEEE 754 float is incapable of representing exactly?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3793838/1606345) and yes, the problem comes with intermediate calculations

Comment: @herugar5: You are wrong - in a general sense. It is corect, it can be represented in C floating points, becuase the language mandates this. However, a smaller format might not be able to. In general, it is a bad idea to rely on floating point to be able to precisely represent a value. Less if operations are involved like `pow`.

Comment: @AlterMann: C does not mandate using IEEE754 floating point with all its implications.

Comment: @Olaf I named the compiler I was using. It does in fact use IEEE754. Can you name any C floating-point implementations that can't exactly represent small integer values?

Comment: @herugar5: gcc uses the format for the targt platform. I'Äm not sure if it does support other platforms, though, or relies on the host and target to havce the same float implementation (I'm not in the mood to verify that right now). Must C targets are not x86 or even ARM. Especially for smaller MCUs, there are floating point formats which cannot represent that value. As I wrote, they are not strictily conforming. Anyway, my comment was a general one, as other readers likely don't hav exactly this value. Let that apart, YOu missed the actual point in my comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when the implementation of `pow` is via

```
pow(x,y) = exp(log(x)*y)
```

Other library implementations first reduce the exponent by integer powers, thus avoiding this small floating point error.

---

More involved implementations contain steps like

```
pow(x,y) {
    if(y<0) return 1/pow(x, -y);

    n = (int)round(y);
    y = y-n;
    px = x; powxn = 1;
    while(n>0) {
        if(n%2==1) powxn *= px;
        n /=2; px *= px;
    }
    return powxn * exp(log(x)*y);
}
```

with the usual divide-n-conquer resp. halving-n-squaring approach for the integer power `powxn`.

Comment: The fuinction has no compliant declaration. As written, it returns an `int` result. And the cast to `int` is wrong. An `int` cannot represent all values a `double` can. FYI: `y` has to be an integer value anyway, see the standard.

Answer (score 1):

You have a nice answer (and solution) from @LutzL, another solution is comparing the difference with an epsilon, e.g.: `0.00001`, in this way you can use the standard function `pow` included in `math.h`

```
#define EPSILON 0.0001
#define EQ(a, b) (fabs(a - b) < EPSILON)

assert(EQ((double)c, pow(oc, opt_count)));
```

Comment: There's no good way to determine what epsilon value is appropriate, and you could easily mask an actual small difference of values. If you want to raise a value to the 2nd power, just multiply it by itself rather than calling `pow()`.

Comment: @KeithThompson, I agree in this case `30. * 30.` is enough, but the power value can come from an user input