# Rounding a f64 to nearest i64 in Rust

Tags: floating-point, rust, precision

Rust's `f64` type provides the function `round()`, which rounds to the nearest integer, but it returns a `f64`. Java's `Math.round(double)`, on the other hand, returns a `long`. I can call `round()` and then cast to `i64`, but will this guarantee that I get the correct result? Here, "correct" means getting the closest `i64` — Java's `round()` returns the "closest long".

Comment: What do you want to happen if the `f64` is integral but out of range of `i64`?

Comment: @ChrisEmerson in this case, Java appears to round `1e100` to `9223372036854775807`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/casting-between-types.html), conversions from floating point to integer types round towards zero, so rounding first is nearly correct: `f.round() as i64`.

However, it's also currently undefined behaviour (but this is [a bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/10184)) if the `f64` is out of range (huge magnitude) of `i64`.  Therefore you should clamp the value first (or possibly better, raise an error or assert).  The possibly obvious answer doesn't work:

```
f.max(std::i64::MIN as f64).min(std::i64::MAX as f64).round() as i64
```

because the conversions of `i64::MAX` to `f64` aren't exact, and applying the above to `1e100` ends up with a large negative value (in my test; as mentioned it's actually undefined).

The best option seems to be to return an error of some if the floating point value is out of the reasonable range your application expects.

Comment: It seems you would need a way to obtain the lower and upper limits of the contiguous range of integral values that fits into a `f64` to be able to either clamp or raise an exception. Otherwise, because of undefined behavior, you cannot actually check the conversion. Maybe the language should expose [those](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793838/which-is-the-first-integer-that-an-ieee-754-float-is-incapable-of-representing-e).

Comment: I agree, in the general case.  But there's probably a limit below those which makes sense for any (ok, most) given application.

Comment: Given that we are talking about 2<sup>53</sup>, yep, there's probably a good limit!

Comment: This bug was finally fixed in Rust 1.45, released July 2020: https://blog.rust-lang.org/2020/07/16/Rust-1.45.0.html#whats-in-1450-stable

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`conv`](https://crates.io/crates/conv) crate for this:

```
use conv::prelude::*;

let x = 9_223_371_487_098_961_920i64 as f64;
println!("{:?}", x.approx_as_by::<i64, RoundToNearest>());
// Ok(9223371487098962944)

let x = 9_223_372_036_854_775_807i64 as f64;
println!("{:?}", x.approx_as_by::<i64, RoundToNearest>());
// Err(FloatError::PosOverflow(..))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple "back of the envelope" implementation:

```
const INTEGRAL_LIMIT: f64 = 9007199254740992.0;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Error {
    NaN,
    Overflow,
    Underflow,
}

fn try_from(f: f64) -> Result<i64, Error> {
    let f = f.round();

    if f.is_nan() { return Err(Error::NaN); }

    if f < -INTEGRAL_LIMIT { return Err(Error::Underflow); }
    if f > INTEGRAL_LIMIT { return Err(Error::Overflow); }

    Ok(f as i64)
}
```

And it comes with a minimal test suite which passes:

```
fn main() {
    assert_eq!(try_from(std::f64::NAN), Err(Error::NaN));

    assert_eq!(try_from(std::f64::NEG_INFINITY), Err(Error::Underflow));
    assert_eq!(try_from(-9007199254740994.0), Err(Error::Underflow));

    assert_eq!(try_from( 9007199254740994.0), Err(Error::Overflow));
    assert_eq!(try_from(std::f64::INFINITY), Err(Error::Overflow));

    assert_eq!(try_from(-INTEGRAL_LIMIT), Ok(-9007199254740992));
    assert_eq!(try_from( INTEGRAL_LIMIT), Ok( 9007199254740992));
}
```

I was actually expecting a `TryFrom` implementation to be available, but found none.