# Efficient arithmetic mean calculation in Python on small and large values

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, floating-point, precision

This is not a question about how to calculate averages in Python, but a question of how to balance precision and speed when comparing the means of two lists of numbers.

This problem was framed in terms of student's grades, so 'typical' inputs to compare were like `[98, 34, 80]` and `[87, 65, 90, 87]`. However I came up against test cases that clearly involved very large numbers as I was getting `OverflowError` on a `return float(average)` on occasion.

There are tests cases like the following, for which using `float()` returns the incorrect answer:

```
x = [9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999,
     9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999,
     9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999]
y = [9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999,
     9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999,
     9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999998]
```

The averages of `x` and `y` are *very* close, but not equal. From what I can see the only way to get the right answer is to use `Decimal` or `Fraction`, but these are slower.

---

Here's a quick performance analysis.

```
def mean_fractions(nums):
    return Fraction(sum(nums), max(len(nums), 1))

def mean_builtins(nums):
    return sum(nums) / float(max(len(nums), 1))

def mean_decimal(nums):
    return Decimal(sum(nums)) / max(len(nums), 1)

# test runner
@timeit
def do_itt(func, input, times):
    for i in range(times):
        func(input)

do_ittt(mean_builtins, y, 1000000) # took: 0.9550 sec
do_ittt(mean_decimal, y, 1000000) # took: 3.0867 sec
do_ittt(mean_fractions, y, 1000000) # took: 3.2718 sec

do_ittt(mean_builtins, [96, 43, 88], 1000000) #  took: 0.7679 sec
do_ittt(mean_decimal, [96, 43, 88], 1000000) # took: 1.4871 sec
do_ittt(mean_fractions, [96, 43, 88], 1000000) # took: 2.6341 sec
```

We can see that using the builtins offers a significant speed-up, even ignoring that if you want to final result to be a `float` you need to convert the `Decimal` and `Fraction` objects.

**Question**

So my question is, given these speed differences, *is there a good way to know when the `builtins` approach would suffice for some lists `a` and `b`, and when it would provide the wrong answer?* On the above `x` and `y` it says they're equal which is wrong, but on `[96, 43, 88]` and `[87, 50]` it works fine.

Comment: Do you actually have to deal with this? It would be considered unusual and specialized for any statistical software to even bother with this. Who even has measurements accurate to 112 decimal places, anyway?

Comment: Also, the average of 0 numbers is not 0. There is no average of a sample of 0 numbers, and a ZeroDivisionError would be an entirely appropriate result if you tried to take that average.

Comment: What are you working on, where does this come from?

Comment: Floats are only useful for values that can be held in a float (up to plus or minus 2^24-1). But here, why don't you use integers to calculate the sum and only resort to float for the final average?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis No, plus/minus 2 ^ **53**. And isn't your suggestion what their `return float(average)` does? Or what their `mean_builtins` does?

Comment: @Stefan: Ah yes, I forgot Python floats are double precision.

Comment: @StefanPochmann this is a Goldman Sachs interview question

Comment: @user2357112 I had to deal with it in a Goldman Sachs issued Hackerrank question.

Comment: @thundergolfer Is it publicly available at HackerRank? Or just for those interviewees?

Comment: @StefanPochmann Not publicly available I'm afraid. Input was list of tuples of (student_name, grade) and output had to be the best average grade rounded down to nearest integer. All the complexity from my perspective was in the floating point arithmetic accuracy issues.

Comment: @thundergolfer Um... uh... if you shall round down to nearest integer anyway... then why are you getting floats involved *at all*?

Comment: @thundergolfer I mean, why not just `sum(nums) // max(len(nums), 1)`?

Comment: @StefanPochmann it is wrong for the `x`, `y` comparison case above.

Comment: Ah, ok. So while you shall report rounded averages, they're not what counts. Then for the comparison, you don't even need to compute the averages. Instead of comparing sum1/len1 with sum2/len2, you could compare sum1*len2 with sum2*len1.

Comment: Where do you get these large numbers from? Possibly they are only unint64 values or are some numbers really larger than 2^64? Do you only have unsigned integer numbers here? Your implementation (summing up and then deviding by len(numbers) is far from optimal. Instead  you have to calculate the integer division and modulus for each number and then summing up the integers and add sum(moduli)/len(nums).

Comment: @max9111 sorry, can you explain this further: " Instead you have to calculate the integer division and modulus for each number and then summing up the integers and add sum(moduli)/len(nums)." What kind of modulo operation? How is this an average calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Assume the original scores are always integers.  Python `float` is a 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point number.  This can represent any integer with 15 or fewer digits in base 10, or [more precisely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793838/which-is-the-first-integer-that-an-ieee-754-float-is-incapable-of-representing-e), it can represent any integer up to 9,007,199,254,740,993.

So if the sum of your scores is more than that, you are likely to have issues using `float` in the way you have outlined.

You are also likely to have issues if, as Stefan Pochmann points out in the comments below, you have large sums but not quite that large:

```
6755399441055745.0 / 3 == 6755399441055746.0 / 3 # True
```

So you need to stay underneath the limit of 15 significant digits for the result of the division as well.  If you divide a 15 digit number by 3 you "lose" one digit because the division may not make the integer part have fewer digits, and it demands an extra digit for the fractional part.  This may mean that a single "spare" significant digit is enough, but even that may not suffice (I haven't tested it).  But certainly, you'd want to use a higher-precision type if the sum of scores is 1 quadrillion or higher.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy [My math is correct](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-10%5E100+%3C+9,007,199,254,740,993). Do you think my "^" means xor instead of power, or did you overlook the minus sign?

Comment: @StefanPochmann: that is nitpicking. Obviously the range -9,007,199,254,740,993 up to 9,007,199,254,740,993 is meant. And in that range, -10^100 does not fit.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: obviously, a student with such a low score would be a total dimwit and could forget his study anyway. <g>

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I know it's nitpicking, almost said that myself. Though I did have a slightly more important point, and you just made it. When you say "range -9,007,199,254,740,993 up to 9,007,199,254,740,993", that's wrong or at least misleading. Because that wording really suggests that -9,007,199,254,740,993 is included. Which is wrong, since that is **not** representable (just like 9,007,199,254,740,993 isn't).

Comment: I used the values posted. I did not check them. So it is `-9,007,199,254,740,992 up to and including 9,007,199,254,740,992`. These are the exactly representable integers.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis No, those are not "the" exactly representable integers. Because that means there are no others. Which is wrong, since there are many others.

Comment: They are exactly representable without "gaps".

Comment: @John Zwinck it doesn't seem to me an issue with the sum of the grades, but with how accurately Python's floating point numbers can represent the fractional representation of those grades' mean. 

Staying within that given range, I think you could find two sets of numbers for which floating point arithmetic would produce the wrong answer.

Comment: @thundergolfer Yeah, I just remembered that you can have different fractions where both numerator and denominator are integers well within this range, but their `float` values are the same. For example `(1e9 / (1e9 + 1) == (1e9 + 1) / (1e9 + 2))` is true.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Can you find an example where the denominators are in a reasonable range for OP?  Say, less than 100,000?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Hey, that takes just 20 GB or so, and even my PC has 32 GB RAM :-). But no, I don't yet know examples with much smaller denominators. I did write about [**the x/(x+1) == (x-1)/x case**](https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/12877/20-line-c-o-n-2-hashing-solution/15) a while back, maybe that can help...

Comment: @JohnZwinck `6755399441055745.0 / 3 == 6755399441055746.0 / 3`