# Crude Monte-Carlo integration goes wrong with more points

Tags: c++, montecarlo

I am using this crude monte-carlo integration technique to find out the value of $\pi$ and noticed that the integration value steadily deviates from the actual value as I increase the number of sample points. The code is:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

float f(float x)//definition of the integrand
{
    return sqrt(1-x*x);
}

float rand1()//random number generator between 0 and 1
{
    float s=rand();
    return s/(RAND_MAX+1.0);
}

float calcint(float xi,float xf,float yi,float yf,float N)//integrator
{
    float n=0;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        float x=(xf-xi)*rand1();float y=(yf-yi)*rand1();
        if (y<f(x))
        {
            n=n+1;
        }
    }
    return n/N*(xf-xi)*(yf-yi);
}

int main()
{
    float N=100000000;
    for (int i=1; i<N; i=i+N/10)//lists integration value for different sampling
    {
        cout<<i<<"\t"<<4*calcint(0,1,0,1,i)<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is,

10000000    3.14188

20000000    3.14059

30000000    2.23696

40000000    1.67772

50000000    1.34218

60000000    1.11848

70000000    0.958698

80000000    0.838861

90000000    0.745654

Why does it happen? Are Monte-carlo integration techniques guaranteed to converge with larger number of sample points?

Comment: First, you are dividing by 0 in `calcInt` when `N` is 0.  Second, you are mixing float and int , expecting no loss of precision.

Comment: I fixed the first problem. But I don't see where I am mixing int and float. I am only comparing them in the condition for the  for statement. I am not really converting them. Could you please elaborate how that may affect the results? And why are they decreasing steadily? If there is a problem in the conversion that might be happening during comparison, then the result should suddenly decrease to a value and stay there.

Comment: Off topic: `if (y < f(x))` can be expressed as `if (y * y < 1 - x * x)`.

Comment: You are mixing float and int in 1)  `for` loop limits `i=i+N/10`   2) Your call to `calcInt` (look at the last parameter).  You are converting them, even though not explicitly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I see those conversions, but still they do not explain why the integration value decreases.  See the accepted answer, I should have declared `n` as integer, or of the same type as `N`. Otherwise, The n stops increasing but N does and that results in a false(smaller) n/N value. Anyway, thanks for the effort. I appreciate it.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I have to binge-learn a lot of monte-carlo techniques and finally apply it in path integrals. So I am trying to be as general as possible.

Comment: Why do you use fp variables to hold integers?

Comment: @curiousguy i need to devide by N. If I don’t use floating point numbers and the result is less than 1, it gives 0. Is there a way to overcome that without mixing them?

Comment: What about changing `n/N*(xf-xi)*(yf-yi)` to `n*(xf-xi)*(yf-yi)/N` ? Also, why do you use floats instead of doubles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is limited precision of `float` type. It has 24 significant precision bits, and the maximal possible integer number that can be represented by `float` type is 16777216 while 16777217 cannot be represented because it requires 25 significant bits (1 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 in binary). See more details here: [Which is the first integer that an IEEE 754 float is incapable of representing exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793838/which-is-the-first-integer-that-an-ieee-754-float-is-incapable-of-representing-e)

It means that when you add 1.0f to 16777216.0f, the result will be 16777216.0f instead of 16777217.0f. Therefore, you should use integer type for `n` instead of floating point type to count the number of events.

Comment: Wow! You are wonderful. I see the problem now. That was so stupid. And yes, it solves the problem.