# C++ `digits10` is 6 for IEEE float, but the first non-representable integer already has 8 digits?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, significant-digits

C++'s [`std::numeric_limits<float>::digits10`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10), is described on cppref as such:

> The value of `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10` is the number of base-10 digits that can be represented by the type T without change, that is, any number with this many decimal digits can be converted to a value of type T and back to decimal form, without change due to rounding or overflow.

A similar description exists for the C cousin [FLT_DIG](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits).

The value given is:

> ```
> float     FLT_DIG /* 6 for IEEE float */
> ```

*However*, it is [shown here on S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793838/which-is-the-first-integer-that-an-ieee-754-float-is-incapable-of-representing-e) that all integers up to `16,777,216` (2<sup>24</sup>) are exactly representable in a 32 bit IEEE float type. And if I can count, that number has **8** digits, so the value for `digits10` should actually be **7**, now shouldn't it?

Rather obviously, I misunderstand something about `digits10` here, so what does this *actually* tell me?

---

Practical applicability:

I was asked if we could store all numbers from `0.00` - `86,400.00` exactly in an IEEE 32 bit float.

Now, I'm very confident that we could store all numbers from `0` - `8,640,000` in an IEEE 32 bit float, but does this hold for the same "integer" range shifted by 2 digits to the left?

Comment: In order to get all 8 of those digits of precision to stay consistent, only the exponent can change. So, 16,777,217 * 2^(x) is going to be represented correctly, but 16,777.217 is likely to lose precision.

Comment: I don't understand the withdrawal of the C tag. From what I can tell, more floating point experts prowl around on the C tag than the C++ one.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: I've done what I think approaches a major edit.

Comment: @Bathsheba hmm alright. I still don't like the implicit assumption that the explanation for both languages is the same, but it is in this special case, so -- fine :)

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Yes I see your point. You could justifiably tag with Java and C# too (if they have the constants defined). It might even be better that way, since those languages mandate IEEE754. In that respect my answer is merely partial.

Comment: If the application of the numbers addresses "fix point" numbers, an alternative approach could be just to use `int` and simply format the output appropriately. Hence, no floating point issues... (Sorry, it's just an idea.)

Comment: @Scheff: That's no bad idea at all, a 64 bit int in particular is a pretty good way of representing money for example, even if you reserve the final 3 digits for the "pence" (you need 3 to support Tunisian Dinar for example. Bitcoin messes everything up).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other answer and comment establishes, `digits10` covers all "exponent ranges", that is it has to hold for `1234567` as well as for `1.234567` and `12345670000` -- and this only holds for **6** digits!

Counter example for 7 digits:

- `8.589,973 e9` vs. `8.589,974 e9` (from cppref example)

Comment: Why is this an answer?

Comment: @PasserBy - because if I personally were to have arrived here via a google search with roughly the understanding I had *before* asking the question, I would *not* have been able to relate my own question to the answer given by Bathsheba. Hence: Shorter self answer, that I personally think is more to the point.

Comment: @MartinBa: My counter example was incorrect; have tested yours and pinched it. Have an upvote so I maintain a clear conscience!

Comment: @chux: I agree with you. What was I thinking?

Answer (score 10):

(Restricting this answer to IEEE754 `float`).

`8.589973e9` and `8.589974e9` both map to `8589973504`. That's a counter-example for an assertion that the 7th significant figure is preserved.

Since no such counter-example exists on the 6th significant figure, `std::numeric_limits<float>::digits10` and `FLT_DIG` are 6.

Indeed integers can be represented exactly up to the 24<sup>th</sup> power of 2. (`16,777,216` and `16,777,217` both map to `16,777,216`). That's because a `float` has a 24 bit *significand*.

Comment: So ... the TL;DR is that `digits10`is *not* about digits, but about *significant* digits over all exponents??

Comment: I'd say it's more to do with *digits* being in your context *denary digits*, but a `float` is about *binary digits*. E.g. `n.5` for integer `n` is exactly representable to the 23rd power of 2, and so on.

Comment: `digits10` *is* about denary digits. Hence the `10`.

Comment: Any number can be written such that all digits in the notation are significant.

Comment: @chux: Ha. Funny I could have swore I checked properly. I'll find a decent one...

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it is easy enough to look for counter examples.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  int p6 = 1e6;
  int p7 = 1e7;
  for (int expo = 0; expo < 29; expo++) {
    for (int frac = p6; frac < p7; frac++) {
      char s[30];
      sprintf(s, "%d.%06de%+03d", frac / p6, frac % p6, expo);
      float f = atof(s);
      char t[30];
      sprintf(t, "%.6e", f);
      if (strcmp(s, t)) {
        printf("<%s> %.10e <%s>\n", s, f, t);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  puts("Done");
}
```

Output

```
<8.589973e+09> 8.5899735040e+09 <8.589974e+09>
<8.796103e+12> 8.7961035080e+12 <8.796104e+12>
<9.007203e+15> 9.0072024760e+15 <9.007202e+15>
<9.223377e+18> 9.2233775344e+18 <9.223378e+18>
<9.444738e+21> 9.4447374693e+21 <9.444737e+21>
<9.671414e+24> 9.6714134744e+24 <9.671413e+24>
<9.903522e+27> 9.9035214949e+27 <9.903521e+27>
<1.000000e+28> 9.9999994421e+27 <9.999999e+27>  This is an interesting one
```

Answer (score 1):

Another point of view:

Consider between each pair of powers-of-2, a `float` like  [IEEE binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) encodes 2<sup>23</sup> values distributed linearly.

---

Example: Between 2<sup>0</sup> and 2<sup>1</sup> or 1.0 and 2.0,

The difference between `float` values is 1.0/2<sup>23</sup> or 10.192e-06.

Written in text form "1.dddddd", a 7 digit number, the numbers have a difference of 1.000e-06.

So for every step of a decimal text number, there are about 10.2 `float`.
No problems encoding these 7 digit numbers.
In this range, no problems encoding 8 digits either.

---

Example: Between 2<sup>23</sup> and 2<sup>24</sup> or 8,388,608.0 and 16,777,216.0.

The difference between `float` values is 2<sup>23</sup>/2<sup>23</sup> or 1.0.

The numbers near the low end written in text form "8or9.dddddd*10<sup>6</sup>", a 7 significant digit number, have a difference of 1.0.

No problems encoding these 7 digit numbers.

---

Example: Between 2<sup>33</sup> and 2<sup>34</sup> or 8,589,934,592.0 and 17,179,869,184.0,

The difference between `float` values is 2<sup>33</sup>/2<sup>23</sup> or 1,024.0.

Numbers near the low end written in text form "8or9.dddddd*10<sup>9</sup>", a 7 significant digit number, have a difference of 1,000.0.

Now we have a problem.  From 8,589,934,592.0, then next 1024 numbers in text form only have 1000 different `float` encoding.

---

7 digits in the form d.dddddd * 10<sup>expo</sup> is too many combinations to uniquely encode using `float`.