# Generic Numeric parameters

Tags: swift, numbers

Is it possible to convert any integer value in to a Double using generics? I'd like to make this function a bit more convenient so I can jam any number in here without having to convert the `hour` and `minute` arguments I pass in to Doubles. Mostly just to get my head around generics more than anything else.

Looking in to Double's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double) the closest thing I can find is Double(exactly: T) but it gives me an optional value while I can't find any protocols that will both support the `+` and `*` operators and allow me to convert to a `Double`. I'd like to do this without creating my own protocol if it's possible.

This doesn't work but illustrates what I'm trying to do:

```
///Returns a Date object for today set to a given time on a 24 hour clock
private func today<T: SignedInteger>(hour: T = 0, minute: T = 0, second: T = 0) -> Date {
    let secondsPastMidnight: Double = Double(exactly: hour)! * 60 * 60 + Double(exactly: minute)! * 60 + Double(exactly: second)!
    return Date().startOfDay.addingTimeInterval(secondsPastMidnight)
}
```

Calling the above like so:

```
let superEarlyMeeting = Meeting(UUID: "0", startTime: today(), endTime: today(hour: SharedGlobals.Calendar.WORK_HOURS_START))
```

Give an error for: `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Double(exactly:)` fails if the integer is not exactly representable
as a 64-bit IEEE-754 floating point number, i.e. for integers [greater
or equal to 9,007,199,254,740,993](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3793950/1187415) in magnitude,
that should not be a problem when working with hours, minutes, and
seconds. (Actually it does not fail at all, which [is a bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4634)).

Alternatively you can convert via the largest signed integer type, e.g.

```
Double(Int64(hour))
```

which returns the closest representable floating point number as a
non-optional.

Comment: When I call the function in my question I get a `Generic parameter T could not be inferred` error. (I've updated the question to show the call). I'm not sure why this appears as my return value isn't generic.

Comment: If you call `today()` with no arguments then the compiler cannot infer the type `T`, that has nothing to do with the conversion from `T` to `Double` inside the function. You have to pass at least one argument, e.g. `today(second: 0)`

Comment: Ah that make's sense, I'll make hours non-optional. Thanks

Comment: Looks like `Double(exactly:)` gives a fatal error whenever I use it. Your alternative works fine.