# Can you safely compare floats to an integer when it is zero?

Tags: java, math, floating-point, precision

I know you can't compare something like `1.0 == 1` safely.

But could you compare something like `0.0 == 0`?

Since floating points can represent the idea of `zero` perfectly, this shouldn't be a problem right?

#### EDIT

---

Another possibly helpful link to future visitors
[Which is the first integer that an IEEE 754 float is incapable of representing exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793838/which-is-the-first-integer-that-an-ieee-754-float-is-incapable-of-representing-e)

Comment: Floating points can also represent the idea of 1.0 perfectly. What is the difference in your understanding to 0.0?

Comment: @Yunnosch I didn't know that either. Could you please provide a citation?

Comment: ["A widening primitive conversion does not lose information about the overall magnitude of a numeric value in the following cases, **where the numeric value is preserved exactly**: \[...\] • from `int` to `double`"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) The notion of "safely" here seems kind of vague to me, though. Whether a particular floating-point comparison is safe depends on what you're actually attempting to do.

Comment: I have marked your question as a duplicate of another that answers it as asked. When a floating-point value is compared to an integer zero, the zero is converted to floating-point. This conversion is exact (the result is exactly zero), and the comparison is exact (it returns true if and only if the floating-point value is exactly zero). I suspect you may have some idea that a floating-point zero might “represent” some number that is approximately zero. That would be a subject for another question, as it does not affect the comparison.…

Comment: … Each floating-point number represents one number exactly. It does not represent an interval or an approximation. If you have a floating-point number that has been produced as the result of some sequence of computations, and you are concerned that it might be zero even though a mathematically perfect computation would have produced a small non-zero number, then you have a different problem than the one you asked about. We can see that because, in such a situation, if you compared the computed result to a floating-point zero instead of an integer zero, it would still produce true.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yeah, I just wanted to run my thoughts by other people for confirmation. In any case, thanks.

Comment: @EricPostpischil... What do you mean? Maybe I wasn't clear with my previous comment. What I meant is that storage of ints, chars, bytes... isn't comparable with float, double. Correct me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: @zlakad A comparison in Java does not compare the bits that represent values. It compares the values. If an `int` is compared to a `float`, the `int` is converted to `float`, and then the values are compared. How they are encoded as bits is not relevant.