# Unity3D - playerpref values changes to negative when its over 2billion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on an idle clicker game and all seems perfect until the money value hits over 2billion, then the value changes to negative.. It seems unity playerpref have an issue with values over 2,154,000,000...how can I fix this, Below code saves and loads the score..

```
public int LoadCoinsAmount()
{
    return PlayerPrefs.GetInt("COINS");
}

public void SaveCoinsAmount(int coins)
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("COINS", coins);
}
```

..Please help

Comment: Please, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking a question.

Comment: This is a math overflow, you are using a int as variable and his max value is 2,147,483,647. change it to double or float to represent higher numbers.

Comment: @AlbertoCh The obvious choice would be the next widest **integral** type (`long`), not a switch to IEEE floating point numbers.

Comment: in this case you could even go for a `System.Numerics.BigInteger`

Comment: All these suggestions are great, but without confirmation from the OP, they are all speculation. Please provide details of the upper bound of your "money value", then you won't get a bunch of confusing and conflicting suggestions.

Comment: Ive added the code i used to save the playerpref..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As I commented you, you should change your variable type, in this case to float which is the only one supported in Unity to save in PlayerPrefs. So your code  would be like:

```
public float LoadCoinsAmount()
{
    return PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("COINS");
}

public void SaveCoinsAmount(float coins)
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("COINS", coins);
}
```

Comment: Yo.. I must say ..You are Awesome.. it worked like a magic.. Thanks

Comment: According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23031245/342842) using floats would **reduce** the available precision (31 bit -> 24 bit).  String-encoded longs would be _much_ better (64 bit), especially in the suggested context of a clicker (unit) counter.

Comment: Fun game of the day: Will this loop ever complete? `for (float i = 16777216f; i < 16777220f; i++) { Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("R")); }` Do you understand why?

Comment: @Sirwhite2015 If `16777216f == 16777217f` (it does), do you think it's wise to proceed with this as a fix to your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Although saving to floats is an option as mentioned by others, I would suggest using the appropriate type which is `long` in this case. A long has higher precision.

To implement:

```
public long LoadCoinsAmount()
{
    string coinString = PlayerPrefs.GetString("COINS");
    if (long.TryParse(coinString, out long result))
    {
        return result;
    }

    return 0;
}

public void SaveCoinsAmount(long coins)
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("COINS", coins.ToString());
}
```