# Why does cmath pow give inaccurate answers?

Tags: c++, c++11, cmath

In C++11:

```
pow(1061,6);   // = 1426567426713180416
```

Check the last 3 digits.
I know for sure that result is wrong, because 1061^6 = 1426567426713180361.

But this other method does it right:

```
long a =1;    
for(int i=0; i<6 ; i++){ a*=1061; }
cout << a;  // = 1426567426713180361
```

pow  is included from cmath.

If anyone knows, I'd like to know why both results aren't equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[std::pow](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) will return double for the integral case and this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3793950/1708801) explains the first integral where double can not longer exactly represent every integral starts at `9007199254740993` after this we may have integers that can not be exactly repsented exactly as a double.

We can see this more easily using the fact that narrowing conversions are ill-formed using uniform initialization. Using the results you desire we see that:

```
double d2{1426567426713180361};
```

is a narrowing conversion ([live godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/r6fWJf))

```
error: constant expression evaluates to 9007199254740993 which cannot be narrowed to type 'double' [-Wc++11-narrowing]
double d1{9007199254740993} ;
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

since it can not be exactly represented. We can also see the number from earlier is also a narrowing conversion:

```
double d1{9007199254740993} ;
```

while:

```
double d3{1426567426713180416};
```

is not.

Answer (score 2):

`pow` uses `double`  for its output, which has approximately 16 decimal digits of accuracy. A 64bit `long` however has 19.

Answer (score 0):

`std::pow` works on `double`s. It does not keep the precision of the resultant number for such large integral values as well as integer arithmetic does.