# Large Arithmetic by MinGW fails

Tags: c++, math, mingw, unsigned-long-long-int

My general task is to compute [image: the sum of a set of positive integers, each multiplied by descending powers of 36, with the first power being the size of the set - 1]According to Wolfram, 
[image: LaTeX for https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9*36%5E6%2B13*36%5E5%2B19*36%5E4%2B6*36%5E3%2B7*36%5E2%2B8*36%2B2]

I expected the following to return the same:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

unsigned long long f(const std::vector<unsigned> &coefficients)
{
    unsigned short exponent = coefficients.size() - 1;
    unsigned long long sum;
    for (unsigned i : coefficients)
    {
        sum += i * pow(36, exponent);
        --exponent;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << f({9,13,19,6,7,8,2});
}
```

but instead it returns `20416905041`.
The minimum capacity of an unsigned long long integer is 0 to 18446744073709551615, according to Alex B on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/what-does-the-c-standard-state-the-size-of-int-long-type-to-be), so capacity doesn't appear to be the problem.

---

Specifications:

- Compiler: x86_64-w64-mingw32 from the Windows TDM-GCC Compiler Suite
- Compiled via `g++ mwe.cpp -std=c++11 -omwe`
- OS: Windows 10 Home

Comment: `pow` is a floating point function and therefore will be susceptible to rounding errors. You should use integer variables (do repeated multiplication by `36`) instead.

Comment: see [Why does cmath pow give inaccurate answers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53159752/1708801)

Comment: Another bug is that you never initialize `sum` (you should set it to `0` before doing `+=` on it)

Comment: @M.M Ah yes, because `sum` is local and therefore not zero-initialized. Also, thanks for the fix.

Comment: @MushroomMan `return std::accumulate(coefficients.begin(), coefficients.end(), 0LL, [&](long long sum, unsigned i) { return sum + i * pow(36, exponent--);});` -- Magic in one line.  [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5883c9d3701bbe6c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [M.M's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53367625/large-arithmetic-by-mingw-fails#comment93611975_53367625) on the question:

> `pow` is a floating point function and therefore will be susceptible to rounding errors. You should use integer variables (do repeated multiplication by 36) instead.