# C Float with a basic integer value giving different results

Tags: c, floating-point

Okay i have a simple question . In my adventure i seek the largest numbers can hold in data types and i was trying things like long int , doubles and floats etc.

But in the simplest assigns such as Float x = 12345789 , it gives me 123456792 as a output .
Here's the code

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
 int x = 1234567891 ;
long int y = 9034567891234567899;
long long int  z = 9034567891234567891;
float t = 123456789 ;
printf("%i \n%li \n%lli \n%f \n ",x,y,z,t);
}
```

and the output im getting is

```
1234567891
9034567891234567899
9034567891234567891
123456792.000000
```

im coding on a linux and using gcc. What could be the problem ?

For clearity , if you give a higher number like

```
float t = 123456789123456789
```

it will get the first 9 right but somekind of rounding in last numbers where it should not .

```
1234567890519087104.000000
```

İ could have understand it if i was working beyond 0 like 0.00123 but its just straight on integers just to find out limits of float.

Comment: Where is the problem? `float` has a limited precision, so it can't represent every number. I think it is about 7 or 8 significant digits (base 10).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @TimRandall Not really a duplicate, but the two links should answer the question.

Comment: yeah i kinda understand it if it was something like 0.00000123 and i could just say its the math of floats but its just a straight forward integer. is it just because , float **only** gets the %70 of the digits right ?

Comment: `float`s do not have an absolute error, they have a relative one. That means: `123456789 = 1.23456789 * 10^8`, if you take 7 significant numbers you get `1.234567 * 10^8`. To get the exact result you have to do the calculations in binary of course.

Comment: Check your question; I can see why assigning 12345789 would not have resulted in 12345789, but it would not result in 123456792, and you actual example does not indicate that.  You have one too many digits at least in the second value.

Comment: See already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793838/which-is-the-first-integer-that-an-ieee-754-float-is-incapable-of-representing-e

Comment: @Clifford oh sorry i wrote it wrong.

Comment: @Osiris Oh ! now i understand the thing after the answer i got , thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- As a visual and experiential learner, I would recommend you to take a good look at how floating point number is represented in the world of bits with a little help of some online converter such as https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

```
    Value:                          123456789
    Hexadecimal representation:     0x4ceb79a3
    Binary representation:          01001100111010110111100110100011
                                    sign    (0)                      : +1
                                    exponent(10011001)               : 2^26
                                    mantissa(11010110111100110100011): 1.8396495580673218
    Value actually stored in float: 1.8396495580673218 * 2^26 = 123456792
    Error due to conversion:        3
```

[float_converter_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3uH5.png)

- Here is a closer look on how the compiler actually does its job: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/C4YyKe

```
int main()
{
    float t = 123456789;
}

main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        movss   DWORD PTR [rbp-4], xmm0
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
.LC0:
        .long   1290500515     //(0x4CEB79A3)
```

[compiler_explorer_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3PdJ.png)

- For your adventure seeking the largest numbers of each data types, I guess your can explore standard header files such as [`float.h`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cfloat/) and [`limits.h`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/).

Answer (score 0):

To find the largest contiguous integer value that can be round-tripped from integer to float to integer, the following experiment could be used:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long i = 0 ;
    float fint = 0 ;

    while( i == (long)fint )
    {
        i++ ;
        fint = (float)i ;
    }

    printf( "Largest integer representable exactly by float = %ld\n", i - 1 ) ;

    return 0;
}
```

However the experiment is largely unnecessary, since the value is predictably  2<sup>24</sup> since 23 is the number of bits in the float mantissa.