# How to convert integer 999999999 to float 999999999.0 instead of 1000000000.0 in C#?

Tags: c#, floating-point, type-conversion, int, data-conversion

In C#, to convert int to float, we just need to do something like `float floatNumber = intNumber` or `Convert.ToSingle(intNumber)`. However, when it comes to large number such as 999999999, the system cannot correctly convert the number but convert it into the unwanted number 1E+09. Now the question is, is it possible to convert that large integer into the wanted float number?

Comment: Look up "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic".  It's something everyone should read, or at least read enough to know why this happens and to know why testing for floating point equality is a **_really_** bad idea.

Comment: Why float rather than double?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A 32-bit float can't exactly represent an integer that large: It only has 24 bits with which to do it (one is implicit in the format).  In 24 bits you can represent 16777215. 16777216 also fits because it is a power of two.  999999999 can't be represented exactly as a number with at most 24 bits multiplied by a power of 2.

See this answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3793950/751579

For more information look up details on IEEE floating point 32-bit and 64-bit formats.

Comment: This a good explanation, but the practical solution would be to use `decimal'.

Comment: @tymtam - Perhaps.  Depends on the OP's use case, which he did not describe.  (E.g., maybe double is appropriate.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use [decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal) type?

```
Console.WriteLine(999999999.0f.ToString("N"));
Console.WriteLine(999999999.0m.ToString("N"));;
```

prints

```
1,000,000,000.00
999,999,999.00
```

---

The [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal#example) even has a example for a very large number

> In this example, the output is formatted by using the currency format string. Notice that `x` is rounded because the decimal places exceed $0.99. The variable `y`, which represents the maximum exact digits, is displayed exactly in the correct format.
>
> ```
> public class TestDecimalFormat
> {
>     static void Main()
>     {
>         decimal x = 0.999m;
>         decimal y = 9999999999999999999999999999m;
>         Console.WriteLine("My amount = {0:C}", x);
>         Console.WriteLine("Your amount = {0:C}", y);
>     }
> }
> /* Output:
>     My amount = $1.00
>     Your amount = $9,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999.00
> */
> ```