# Does a value x of type float exist for which x + 1 == x?

Tags: c++, floating-point, type-conversion

This was a question in an exam but no clear explanation why.
It was a true/false type question with;

> There exists a value x of the type float for that holds: x + 1 == x...

Which is true. Why tho?

I guess it has to do with type conversion? But I can't imagine how that would work.

Comment: What's the largest possible float value plus one?

Comment: @jonrsharpe that value is undefined

Comment: I like this exam question. It can be rewritten as, "Why shouldn't you use float for keeping track of time?"

Comment: This is also related to comparing floats with equality being fraught with problems as well.  This is due to the inaccuracy of representing numbers precisely.  Good test question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is the first integer that an IEEE 754 float is incapable of representing exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793838/which-is-the-first-integer-that-an-ieee-754-float-is-incapable-of-representing-e)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure.

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    float f = std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity();
    std::cout << (f == f + 1) << std::endl;
}
```

As Deduplicator points out, if your `float` is big enough (works for me with `float f = 1e20;`), it'll also work because the added `1` would be outside of the `float`'s accuracy.

[Try it online](https://onlinegdb.com/HyQk1KdfH)

Comment: No need to go to infinity, `1` pales to insignificance long before. Though admittedly, going all the way is simpler.

Comment: @Deduplicator Thanks for pointing this out, I forgot about this. Added it to answer. I think that might have been the actual answer that OP's exam was looking for because it demonstrates the limitations of floating point numbers.

Comment: Not all floating point representations support infinities either.   In C++11, a value `x` for which `std::nextafter(x) - x > 2.0` will probably also give a value `x` for which `x == x + 1` will test true.

Answer (score 3):

This code compiles without error:

```
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity() == std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity() + 1.0f, "error");
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity() == std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity() + 1.0, "error");
    return 0;
}
```

[online version](https://onlinegdb.com/H1bw1FOMB)

---

You don't need to even use infinity. If the number is big enough, rounding errors become big enough so adding one to the number doesn't change it at all.
E.g.

```
static_assert(100000000000000000000000.f == 100000000000000000000000.f + 1.0, "error");
```

The specific number of `0` you have to put here may be implementation defined, though.

Always keep rounding in mind when you write programs that use floating point numbers.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float val = 1e5;
    while (val != val + 1)
        val++;
    std::cout << val << "\n";
    return 1;
}
```

Prints `1.67772e+07` for [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/rqq2cj).

> There exists a value x of the type float for that holds: x + 1 == x... which is true. Why tho?

The reason for that lies in [how floating point numbers work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). Basically a 32bit float has 24 bits for the mantissa (the base digits) and 8 bits for the exponent. At some point +1 just doesn't cause a change in the binary representation because the exponent is too high.

Comment: Yes, 2^24 = 16777216 and 16777217 can't be represented exactly with an IEEE754 32-bit float: `float(16777217) == 16777216.0`. The same holds for every odd number after that.

Answer (score 1):

For a 32-bit IEEE754 float (a.k.a. single-precision or SP), the minumum non-negative normal such value is `16777216`. That is, `16777216 + 1 == 16777216`.

The number `16777216` is precisely `2^24`. An SP float has 23 bits of mantissa. This is how it is represented internally:

```
                  3  2          1         0
                  1 09876543 21098765432109876543210
                  S ---E8--- ----------F23----------
          Binary: 0 10010111 00000000000000000000000
             Hex: 4B80 0000
       Precision: SP
            Sign: Positive
        Exponent: 24 (Stored: 151, Bias: 127)
       Hex-float: +0x1p24
           Value: +1.6777216e7 (NORMAL)
```

You can see the entire mantissa is 0. If you add 1 to this number, it'll hit the gap and be absorbed, giving you back precisely what you started with.