# How do I assign a numpy.int64 to a torch.cuda.FloatTensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

Im not able to assign int64 to torch tensor. I have got the following tensor

```
tempScale = torch.zeros((total, len(scale))).cuda() if useGpu else torch.zeros((nbPatchTotal, len(scale)))
```

In my code, when I'm using the following line, it's throwing an error message

```
tmpScale[:, j] = scale
```

The error message is

`TypeError: can't assign a numpy.int64 to a torch.cuda.FloatTensor`

what am I missing?

Comment: What does `scale` contain? You might try `scale.astype('float64')`.

Comment: @kHarshit that won't work, especially considering one is a GPU tensor and one is a numpy array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to convert `scale` to a torch tensor of the same type and device as `tmpScale` before assignment.

```
tmpScale[:, j] = torch.from_numpy(scale).to(tmpScale)
```

Note that this is casting `scale` from an `int64` to a `float32` which will likely result in a [loss of precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793838/which-is-the-first-integer-that-an-ieee-754-float-is-incapable-of-representing-e) if values in `scale` have magnitude larger than 2<sup>24</sup> (about 16 million).