# the other 2 Pythagorean triplets for a given number

Tags: c++

so I was recently trying out a question and wrote some code but I couldn't manage to pass more than 3 test cases out of 5.
**the ques is**: Given a number N (denoting one of the legs of the triangle), Print its Pythagoras pair in increasing order if they exist. Otherwise, print "-1".

**Input Format**
A single integer N

**Constraints**
N <= 10^9

**Output Format**
Two numbers X and Y denoting the rest of the numbers of the Pythagorean triplet in increasing order.

**Sample Input**
3
**Sample Output**
4 5

**My Solution:**

```
   #include<iostream>
    #include<cmath>
    using namespace std;
    int main() {    
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        if(n>=0 && n<=2){
            cout<<"-1"<<endl;
            }
        else if (n%2==0){
            cout<<pow((n/2),2)-1<<" "<<pow((n/2),2)+1<<endl;
        }
        else if (n%2==1){
            cout<< 2*((n-1)/2)*((n+1)/2) <<" "<<pow((n+1)/2,2) + pow((n-1)/2,2)<<endl;
        }

        else{
            cout<<"-1"<<endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

can someone suggest what am i missing in this ?

Comment: A Pythagorean triplet consists of integers. `pow` produces a floating point number. A good first step would be writing an integer-squaring function.

Comment: ... and if you use a set of known triplets, you should be able to find where it breaks down. You can use [this](https://godbolt.org/z/_-WEwV) to start testing.

Comment: final `else` is never reached...

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues you could address.

- The chained `if`s should be modified (as noted in the comments, the last `cout<<"-1"<<endl;` is never reached) and could be simplified (if a number is not even, it's odd).
- The code reads `int` values, but the constraints state that the number could be as big as 10<sup>9</sup>. A `long int` is guaranteed to be able to store such value.
- To square the values, a call to [`std::pow(..., 2);`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) is used. Since C++11, if any argument has integral type, it is cast to `double` and the return value is also of type `double`. This may introduce rounding errors that an integral calculation (with an integral type having a big enough size) wouldn't have. Note that, given the constraints, (0.5 * 10<sup>9</sup>)<sup>2</sup> = 2.5 * 10<sup>17</sup> which is bigger than 2<sup>53</sup> + 1 (~9 * 10<sup>15</sup>), the [first integer number not exactly representable by an IEE 754 `double`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793838/which-is-the-first-integer-that-an-ieee-754-float-is-incapable-of-representing-e).
- The posted algorithm finds *a* triple, but a number may appear in many of them. E.g. given 20 as input, the posted code outputs

  `99 101`

  Other possible triples beeing (20, 21, 29) or (20, 15, 25).

That said, a possible implementation could be the following

```
#include <iostream>

long long int square(long int x)
{
    return static_cast<long long int>(x) * x;
}

int main()
{    
    long int n;
    while (std::cin >> n) {
        if( n <= 2 ) {
            std::cout << "-1\n";
        }
        else {
            if ( n % 2 == 0 ) {
                long long int q = square(n / 2);
                std::cout << (q - 1) << " " << (q + 1) << '\n';
            }
            else {
                long long int q = square(n);
                std::cout << (q - 1)/2 << " " << (q + 1)/2 << '\n';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The **legs** of a right triangle are the two sides that intersect to determine the right angle. The remaining side is called the **hypotenuse**. So we *have to print one remaining leg other than the input and the hypotenuse*.

**Solution Approach:**

If m>n>0 are integers, then (m2-n2, 2mn, m2+n2) is a Pythagorean triple. This is easily seen with a bit of algebra. Thus, plugging in various (m,n) will give various triples.
Now, our goal is to find a triple of the form (m2-n2, 2mn, m2+n2) in which our input value is one of the catheti(legs). Note that the catheti are m2-n2 and 2mn. Also, note that the second cathetus is always even. Thus, it makes sense to consider two cases:

If a is even, then let’s try to equate it with the second cathetus, 2mn, i.e., let’s try to find an (m,n) pair such that 2mn = a. In this case, is even, so we can divide by 2. We have mn = a/2. Thus, all we have to do is to find a factorization of a/2 into mn such that m>n. You can try various factoring methods — even naïve O(√a) time method will pass - but in this case , we don’t really even need to do that, since the trivial (m,n) = (a/2,1) works!. This gives us the solution triple ( (a^2)/4 - 1, a, (a^2)/4 + 1 ). Note that (a^2)/4 is an integer since a is even.

If a is odd, then we can’t equate it with the second cathetus, so let’s try instead m2-n2, i.e. we want to find an (m,n) such that m2-n2 = a. Node that m2-n2 = (m+n)(m-n), so all boils down again to factoring! Let’s try our trivial factorization again: (m+n, m-n) = (a,1) What we get is a system of two linear equations: m+n=a and m-n=1 which has solution m=(a+1)/2 and n=(a-1)/2. Substituting back, this gives us the triple (a, (a^2 - 1)/2, (a^2 + 1)/2). Note that (a^2 + 1)/2 is an integer as a is odd.

```
int main()
{
  long long n;
  cin>>n;
  if (n<=2)
    cout<<"-1";
  else if (n % 2 == 0)
  {
    // Calculating for even case
    long long var = 1 * n * n / 4;
    cout<<var - 1<<" ";
    cout<<var + 1;
  }
  else if (n % 2 != 0)
  {
    //Calculating for odd case
    long long var = 1 * n * n + 1;
    cout<<var / 2 - 1<<" ";
    cout<<var / 2;
  }
return 0;
}
```