# Division by order 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, precision

I'm currently writing a program that checks for the multiplicity of a number by a factor of 10. **However, this program is violated by what I assume is a double-precision error in python.** I have attached an example below.

```
# correct representation in line with expectation
>> 71885 / 71.885 = 1000.0

# this fails, when we should be reporting 10^6 (1000000)
>> 310888679 / 310.888679 = 999999.99999999
```

Comment: It's not a strict duplicate, but this is basically a different question with the answer [yep, floating point math is "broken"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/364696). This isn't specific to Python, basically everyone agrees on a definition of binary floating point that can't accurately represent many simple decimal values. `310.888679` is actually a value very slightly larger than that (`310.888679000000024643668439239…`), so when you divide using it, the result is ever so slightly smaller than expected.

Comment: use math.isclose() -

Comment: I'll have to work around this issue it seems. I won't be able to math.isclose() in my context, unfortunately.

Comment: I thought I had a good answer to this, but it's actually _still_ bitten by IEEE 754 floating point math See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/64902818/4541045

Comment: Totally agree it's a dup of the linked question, FWIW.