# Explain the output of this python script?

Tags: python

**For counting number of zero's in a number ..**

```
def cal(l):
    r = 0
    o = 0
    while (r == 0):
        r = l % 10
        o += 1
        l = int(l / 10)
    return o-1
```

[image: Here is the output...]

So when the input is greater than 10^23 output is 1. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int(l / 10)` is floating point division, which is inaccurate as your numbers grow larger([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793838/which-is-the-first-integer-that-an-ieee-754-float-is-incapable-of-representing-e)). Change it to `l // 10`, which is integer division and has no accuracy issues.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use arithmetic operations to count characters. Use string operations instead, for example [`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=count#str.count) for simple strings, or [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall) for something more complex, which requires regular expressions:

```
import re
for n in [1, 0.1, 10.0, 10**23, 10**24]:
    print(str(n).count('0'))
    # or this:
    # print(len(re.findall(r'0', str(n))))
# 0
# 1
# 2
# 23
# 24
```

Comment: str.count instead of re?

Comment: @SuperStormer: Thank you for the suggestion to use a simpler `str.count` instead of `re`. Updated the answer.