# What happens when you assign a large float number to an int () function

Tags: python, integer, rounding-error

Python Documents says,

> For floating point numbers, this truncates towards zero.
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=int#int

But when I tried assign a large float number to an int () function, it doesn't work well.

```
>>> int(11111111111111111/2)
5555555555555556
>>> 11111111111111111//2
5555555555555555
```

What happen??
(rounding error??)

Comment: Hint: what happens when you try `11111111111111111/2`, *without* the `int`? What happens if you try `float(11111111111111111)`?

Comment: `5555555555555555.5` has too many digits of precision for floating point, it can't be represented exactly.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793838/which-is-the-first-integer-that-an-ieee-754-float-is-incapable-of-representing-e

Comment: >>> float(1111111111111111111)
1.1111111111111112e+18

This is very simple and essential answer !
Thank you so much!!