# How ceil function works in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point, ceil

When I execute this code the value of `ans1`, `ans2` is `50002896` and `50005000`.
I know there is some issues with `ceil` function but was not able to figure out the exact cause.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
      long long ans1 = 0, ans2 = 0;

      for (long long i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
      {
            ans1 = ans1 + ceil((float)i / 1);
            ans2 = ans2 + i;
      }
      cout << ans1 << " " << ans2 << endl;
}
```

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` -- Include the proper header files, not this one.

Comment: It's probably because of `(float)` not because of `ceil`. `float` is not fully accurate.

Comment: By not using the proper *standard* header files, plus the usage of `using namespace std;` without knowing what that non-standard header file is pulling, in, we don't know if it is `std::ceil` or `ceil` from the C runtime library.  That's why using `bits...whatever` is a bad idea, let alone it isn't standard.

Comment: [Different results when using `std::ceil` and `ceil`](https://godbolt.org/z/brhs6sEhs)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Without the `cmath` header, compilation fails with `c++11`, `c++14`, `c++17`, and `c++20` flags: error: 'ceil' is not a member of 'std' — I'm not sure how `ceil()` and `std::ceil()` differs.

Comment: @RohanBari There is no guarantee of compilation if you don't include the proper header files.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sidenote, using `ceil`(no `std::`) can also result different results based on importing `<cmath>` or `<math.h>`

Comment: @Ranoiaetep -- Yes, that's why using the non-standard "include everything" header is problematic.

Comment: @Chinnmay B S Why a `float` cast in `ceil((float)i / 1)` instead of `double` or `long double`?

Comment: Also, instead of using the `ceil((some_float / 1))` to cast a floating point number to integer, use `std::lround` and `std::llround` instead.

Comment: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/995714), [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the problem is not the `ceil` function, but rather that not all integers can be represented accuratly as floating point values.

Some more info about floating point representation: [Wikipedia IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). And a related post: [Which is the first integer that an IEEE 754 float is incapable of representing exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793838/which-is-the-first-integer-that-an-ieee-754-float-is-incapable-of-representing-e).

The following code is a minimal demonstration of the same issue that causes your issue:

```
float f1 = 100000000;
f1++;
std::cout << std::to_string(f1) << std::endl;
```

[Wrong] Output (expected: +1):

```
100000000.000000
```

One approach would be to use `double` instead of `float`.
This will **not** solve the principle issue, but will make the range of representable integers **a lot bigger**:

```
double f1 = 100000000;
f1++;
std::cout << std::to_string(f1) << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
100000001.000000
```

**Some side notes:**

1. better to avoid `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` - see here: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).
2. better to avoid `using namespace std` - see here [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 1):

First, try to use specific headers like #include , in this case, .because #include <bits/stdc++.h> will bring lots of junk.

**So the issue is with float not ceil explained below**

floating-point values do not represent exact values.

Code:-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// Driver Code
int main()
{
    float num1 = 10000.29;
    float num2 = 10000.2;

    // Output should be 0.0900000000
    cout << std::setprecision(15)
        << (num1 - num2);
    return 0;
}
```

Output :-

```
0.08984375
```